# Add product price to all products on plugin activation

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to add a further product price to all existing products on plugin activation. But the activation process stops after about 5 seconds and so the product price is only added to 24 of 60 products. The plugin activation fails.

I don't know why the activation process stops. How can I solve this problem and add the price to all products?

Here is my code:

```
public function activate(ActivateContext $activateContext): void
{
    // Get rule
    $ruleRepository = $this->container->get('rule.repository');
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', 'XYZ'));
    /** @var RuleEntity $rule */
    $rule = $ruleRepository->search($criteria, $activateContext->getContext())->first();
    $ruleId = $rule->getId();

    // Add pricing rule to all products
    $productRepository = $this->container->get('product.repository');
    $products = $productRepository->search(new Criteria(), $activateContext->getContext());
    $productPriceRepository = $this->container->get('product_price.repository');
    /** @var ProductEntity $product */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productPriceRepository->create([[
            'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
            'productId' => $product->getId(),
            'quantityStart' => 1,
            'ruleId' => $ruleId,
            'price' => [
                [
                    'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,
                    'gross' => $product->getCurrencyPrice(Defaults::CURRENCY)->getGross(),
                    'net' => $product->getCurrencyPrice(Defaults::CURRENCY)->getNet(),
                    'linked' => true
                ]
            ],
        ]], $activateContext->getContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code please? I'm just guessing wild that the code leaks to much memory

Comment: I think changing the prices of all products right on activation of a plugin is a bad idea. Such tasks should be done manually after the plugin is installed with a CLI command and /or batch processing

Comment: @dnaumann I added my code to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code needs to much memory, cause the shopware 6 dal is very expensive on memory. As Michael T said, you should avoid such expensive operations in the installation or activation process of a plugin. The best practices would be to write a) a CLI command which needs to be executed manually after installation (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-custom-commands), or b) if you dont want manual actions create entries in a queue which are handled by a message handler (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/message-queue/add-message-handler)

Comment: Why would a CLI command that does the same use less memory? Are there different memory limits for CLI and the plugin activation (if they both executed using the same `php.ini` `memory_limit` of course)

Answer (score 3):

The lifecycle events of plugins really are not supposed to handle large scale write operations like that. Without knowing the quantity of products this could easily be an issue caused by memory exhaustion. To verify that you could set a reasonable limit to your criteria:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria(); 
$criteria->setLimit(50);
```

Aside from that `ProductEntity::getCurrencyPrice()` returns `?Price`, so you want to check if it returns `null` before calling `getGross` and `getNet`. I'd recommend taking this code out of the lifecycle handler and to add it to a [custom CLI command](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-custom-commands) instead.